# How to launch a specific page/functionalitiy in another application with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently working on an application that will link to other applications with searches or just by clicking on buttons. I am programming it in C# and Xamarin.Android.

Currently, i can open another application. But i can't figure out how to open a specific page/functionality in that other application. Example: opening the settings page in Google's Youtube app.

```
Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
StartActivity(intent);
```

I have two problems at the moment:

1. How can I know the right URL/URI in the 3rd party app?
2. How can I launch another page/functionality in the 3rd party app?

Comment: it really depends on whether or not the other application supports it

Comment: How do you know if other applications support it? And when they do, how to implement?

Comment: you have to research each application

Comment: Agree with Jason, It dependence on 3rd party app. if that open the interface for others applications. If they did not open interface, this operation cannot be executed.